# Download sqlite database results in empty database

Tags: ios, sqlite, download, filesystems

I am developing an iOS app that is based on a sqlite database. Since I don't want to update the application each time I add new data, I would like to store the sqlite database on a server and ask the user if he wants to download an update.

Here is my code:

```
    NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myurl.com/dl.php"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL]];
    [data writeToFile:storePath atomically:YES];
```

dl.php simply sends the sqlite database to the client (php: readfile("foo.sqlite")). When I visit the url in my browser, the database is correctly downloaded (336 KB).

I als tried:

```
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:storePath error:error];
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:storePath contents:data attributes:nil];
```

My problem: The file gets downloaded, but the sqlite database is only 188 KB (instead of 336 KB). The file is not completely corrupted. If I open the file with a sqlite database editor, the table structure is correct, but there is no data in the sqlite file.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does `[data bytes]` in your first rendition report?

Comment: Nitpick - the first line should be `NSString *stringURL = @"http://myurl.com/dl.php";`. Don't use `stringWithFormat:` unless you actually have a string format.

Comment: @user1792043 Also, are you entirely confident that this 188 kb file was downloaded versus, for example, a copy of a blank database that might have been sitting around in your bundle already? It seems very unlikely that SQLite could open a fragment of a database without reporting a file corruption error.